# How can I create new global css classes on the fly in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I’m using Draft.js for a project. I created a component that allows you to choose a font from a menu, then apply that font to the selected text in the Draft.js editor.

The way I need to do this:

1. Dynamically add a `@font-face` rule for the selected font that includes the font name and file location;
2. Create a *new* CSS class containing the `font-family` property that uses the font name from the `@font-face` rule that was added; and
3. Apply that new CSS class to the selection.

I’ve gotten everything but #2 figured out. For #2, I’m not finding any clear methods or tools to use that allow me to create new CSS classes in the global space. I’m reading a lot about css-in-js, but everything seems bloated or overly complex.

I’m formatting the `@font-face` rule and class like this:

```
const newClass = {
    '@font-face': [
        {
            fontFamily: `${font.label} ${FONT_FAMILY_PREFIX}-A`,
            src: `url(/fonts/${font.value}-TD-Space.woff)`,
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontStyle: 'normal',

        }, {
            fontFamily: `${font.label} ${FONT_FAMILY_PREFIX}-B`,
            src: `url(/fonts/${font.value}-TD.woff)`,
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontStyle: 'normal',
        },
    ],
    [`.${font.value}`]: {
        fontFamily: `${font.label} ${FONT_FAMILY_PREFIX}-A, ${font.label} ${FONT_FAMILY_PREFIX}-B`,
    },
})
```

But I’m just not sure *where* to put it so it’s accessible across the app.

Does this require the help of some package or is there a simpler way I can manage it without?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use React's Context feature ([docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html))

Basically, you define a context like this:

```
// style-context.js

export const Styles = {
  style1: {
    fontFamily: '"Times New Roman", Times, serif',
    fontSize: '12px'
  },
  style2: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSize: '16px'
  },
};

export const StyleContext = React.createContext({
    theme: styles.style1, // default value
    changeTheme: (newTheme) => {}
  }
);
```

Then, you wrap your App like this:

```
// App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FontContext, styles } from './style-context'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Function to change the theme
    this.chooseTheme = (newTheme) => {
      this.setState({
        theme: styles[newTheme]
      })
    }

    // State includes the current theme and function to change it
    this.state = {
      theme: styles.style1,
      chooseTheme: this.chooseTheme
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Wrap with the context's Provider, and pass in the theme from
      // the state. Those state values will be available from all
      // children, no matter how deep.
      <StyleContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <div className="App">
          {/* components */}
        </div>
      </StyleContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

There are two ways to use the context, then. First, you can reference it in any child component like this:

```
// SomeComponent.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {StyleContext} from './style-context'

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={
        this.context.theme
      }>
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
SomeComponent.contextType = StyleContext

export default SomeComponent
```

Really simple. The other way to access it is like this, which is useful if you have multiple Contexts you're combining on a single Component:

```
// TestButton.js

import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {StyleContext} from './style-context'

class TestButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyleContext.Consumer>
        {
          // The contents of the Consumer tag will receive the
          // 'value' prop set at the Provider level, which is,
          // in this case, the App state containing the current
          // theme and function to change it
          ({theme, chooseTheme}) => (
            <button onClick={() => {chooseTheme('style2')}} style={theme}>Change Font</button>
          )
        }
      </StyleContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

export default TestButton
```

Doing that will mean you don't need to programmatically change the classes that different divs are given, nor need to generate CSS classes in the first place.

Also, one of my favorite tricks for assigning styles is to use `Object.assign()` to do so, like this:

```
...
<div style={Object.assign(
  { backgroundColor: 'red', fontSize: '16px' },
  this.context.theme
)}>
...
```

That way, you can set default values, decoupling the Context from the Component, and allows the theme's style attributes to only override matching keys, combining the rest.